# sphinx return everything using Query

Tags: sphinx

Is it possible to return everything? when $words=""
$result = $cl->Query( $words, 'test1' );
it returns nothing, is there a way for it to return everything?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `*`.

Answer (score 0):

What matching mode do you use?

For full scan, you can use SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN search mode.

Also, SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2 support fullscan, simply put empty string into Query function as you did.